# for loop with condition to streams

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have the following code:

```
public List<Person> getStudents() {
    List<Person> students = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i = 0; !found; i++) {
      //some logic
    }

    return students;
}
```

Is there a way to convert that for loop to use java 8 streams? I'm just playing with streams to learn.

Comment: There are IDEs that provide ways to convert loops to streams to a certain extent. Not really sure of a library/plugin alternate that helps with such transformations. People here generally reach out with their attempt and what they are stuck with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9), you can use `takeWhile`

For example

```
List<DateBucket> buckets =
    IntStream.iterate(0,i->i+1)
             .mapToObj(i -> new SimpleEntry<>(fromDate.plus(i * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit),
                                              fromDate.plus((i + 1) * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit)))
             .takeWhile(entry -> !toDate.isBefore(entry.getValue()))
             .map(entry -> new DateBucket(entry.getKey().toInstant(), entry.getValue().toInstant()))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

For time-based units, you can use the overload of `iterate` that takes a condition to determine whether the stream should continue:

```
return Stream.iterate(fromDate, // initial element
    x -> !toDate.isBefore(x), // whether the stream should continue
    x -> x.plus(bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit)) // next element
    .map(x -> new DateBucket(x.toInstant(), x.plus(bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit).toInstant()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This version sometimes produces buckets that are a little different from your for loop when the unit is date based, because I am adding the units separately, rather than in one whole scoop. Compare `LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 31).plusMonths(2)` and `LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 31).plusMonths(1).plusMonths(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate stream from `fromDate` and use `takeWhile` till the condition is reached. Like this:

```
AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
        
List<DateBucket> buckets = Stream.generate(()->fromDate.plus((i.getAndIncrement()+1)*bucketSize,bucketSizeUnit))
    .takeWhile((d)->!toDate.isBefore(d.minus(bucketSize,bucketSizeUnit)))
    .map((d1)-> new DateBucket(d1.minus(bucketSize,bucketSizeUnit).toInstant(),d1.toInstant()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Demo code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ZonedDateTime to = ZonedDateTime.now();
        ZonedDateTime from = to.minus(5, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

        List<DateBucket> db = bucketize(from,to,1,ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println(db);
        
        db = bucketizeWithStream(from,to,1,ChronoUnit.DAYS);
        System.out.println(db);
    }

    static List<DateBucket> bucketizeWithStream(ZonedDateTime fromDate, ZonedDateTime toDate, int bucketSize,
            ChronoUnit bucketSizeUnit) {
        AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
        
        List<DateBucket> buckets = Stream.generate(()->fromDate.plus((i.getAndIncrement()+1)*bucketSize,bucketSizeUnit))
                .takeWhile((d)->!toDate.isBefore(d.minus(bucketSize,bucketSizeUnit)))
                .map((d1)-> new DateBucket(d1.minus(bucketSize,bucketSizeUnit).toInstant(),d1.toInstant()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return buckets;
    }
    static List<DateBucket> bucketize(ZonedDateTime fromDate, ZonedDateTime toDate, int bucketSize,
            ChronoUnit bucketSizeUnit) {
        List<DateBucket> buckets = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean reachedDate = false;
        for (int i = 0; !reachedDate; i++) {
            ZonedDateTime minDate = fromDate.plus(i * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
            ZonedDateTime maxDate = fromDate.plus((i + 1) * bucketSize, bucketSizeUnit);
            reachedDate = toDate.isBefore(maxDate);
            buckets.add(new DateBucket(minDate.toInstant(), maxDate.toInstant()));
        }

        return buckets;
    }
}
record DateBucket(Instant from, Instant to) {
    public String toString() {
        return from.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).getDayOfMonth() + "-" + to.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).getDayOfMonth();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[6-7, 7-8, 8-9, 9-10, 10-11, 11-12]
[6-7, 7-8, 8-9, 9-10, 10-11, 11-12]
```

Note: this is just and idea. Fix\improve the code as per your needs.